# Best Practice for maintaining a TSQL database creation script for a web application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, web-applications

We have a ASP.NET web application and need to maintain the database creation and initialization script.

Are there any industry best practices that people know of for maintaining database creation and initialization scripts.  I can think of two main approaches.

1. Maintain a tsql creation script directly by hand.
2. Maintain a master database and create the script that is then checked into source safe.

Also the script should be able to be tracked through source control, i.e. table order should be controllable.

If possible should also include the ability to track initialisation data either in the same or a seperate script.

Currently we generate the script from management studio but the order of the tables seems to be random.

And the more automated the solution the better.

Comment: I believe we use whatever Visual Studio provides, I'll look into details tomorrow (I need to, cuz it doesn't handle indexed views...)

Comment: why not use a database project? VS has a template for it and i think you can do all that things.

Comment: We only have the cheapest version of VS

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not maintaining the script, nor maintaining a 'master' copy of the database. The real problem is *upgrading* existing database(s). You do your modification in the developer environment, which are then propagated to the test environment, and finally pushed into production environment. While at developer and test environment stage is possible to start from scratch, in production you always have to upgrade the existing deployment.

In my experience the best practice is to use [upgrade scripts](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/15/version-control-and-your-database/). This practice is useful even with a single deployed site, but it becomes invaluable with multiple locations that may be at different versions. But even with one single operational site is still useful to be able to test the upgrade repeatedly (starting from backups of current version), keep the changes in source control, have a well formalized and peer reviewed change procedure (the upgrade script). And upgrade scripts can be tailored to specific needs of the operational site, like handling a large table with special care, or deal with encrypted data, or whatever one of the myriad of the details diff based tools neglect or ignore. The main disadvantage is the the scripts have to be written, which require real T-SQL knowledge (forget all the 'designers' in you favorite management tool).

Comment: Another disadvantage of upgrade scripts is that - unless coupled with entire database create scripts - you can't easily recreate or redeploy the database. If you want to create a new environment for testing or developing you need to backup & restore from an existing environment. It works but it's not ideal.

Comment: The upgrade script from v. 0 to v.1 is the one that deploys the initial database (ie. the 'create').

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out [RedGate SQL Source Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/).

Comment: Looks nice but there's the issue of convincing the boss to by it

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [Visual Studio Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193266.aspx)?

I use database projects to store all database objects (tables, views, functions, keys, triggers, indexes across schemas) and keep versioning in TFS. You can build the database to ensure that everything is valid. You can deploy to a fresh database, or do a schema comparison with an existing database.

I also keep all reference and setup data in post deployment scripts which are automatically run after deployment.

Comment: may be useful but we only have vs standard which doesn't include them